# Better way to do class type alias?

Tags: flutter, dart

From time to time, I would like to call a class differently depending on the context or to reduce duplication.

Let's assume, I have the following classes defined:

```dart
// in file a.dart
class A {
  final String someprop;
  A(this.someprop)
}

// in file b.dart
abstract class BInterface {
  String get someprop;
}

class B = A with EmptyMixin implements BInterface;
```

For this syntax to check out, I have to define `EmptyMixin` so that the syntax is OK. 
Do you know of a better/prettier way to do this "aliasing" in Dart?

Comment: The `B` class here is no better than `class B extends A implements BInterface { B(super.someProp);}. You should just use the latter because it's clearer what's going on. Dart does have general type aliases now, but they do not allow you to add new interfaces.

Answer (score 1):

I'm afraid the way you're doing it is the prettiest way to do this at the moment. There is a very old, but still open and active issue: https://github.com/dart-lang/sdk/issues/2626 that proposes the `typedef B = A;` syntax for aliasing types.